# dplyr lag of different group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to mutate both a column containing the samegroup lag of a variable as well as the lag of (one of) the other group(s).
Edit: Sorry, in the first edition, I messed up the order a bit by rearranging by date at the last second.

[image: Original df]

This is what my desired result would look like:

[image: Desired Outcome df]
Here is a minimal code example:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2)
df <-
  data.frame(
    x =  sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), 10),
    group = sample(c("A","B"),10,replace = T),
    value = sample(1:10,size=10)
  ) %>% arrange(x)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(own_lag = lag(value))


df %>% data.frame(other_lag = c(NA,1,2,7,7,9,10,10,8,6))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Interesting question but I could follow your logic. How is the `other_lag` for 5th row and 6th row calculated?

Comment: I think `findInterval` in some logic would be useful here.

Comment: @mt1022 Sorry, rearranging by date right before posting had messed up the data a little bit. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: By 'lag of another group', do you mean that for the nth item in group 1 you wish to have the (n+lag)th item in a different group? If so, then add an incrementing column to to each group (like rownumber) and join the groups based on that.

Comment: From my understanding, the second item in "other_lag" should be 1 instead of NA, is that correct?

Comment: @docendo discimus you are of course absolutely right.

Answer (score 7):

A solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)

# to create own lag: 
setDT(df)[, own_lag:=c(NA, head(value, -1)), by=group]

# to create other group lag: (the function works actually outside of data.table, in base R, see N.B. below)
df[, other_lag:=sapply(1:.N, 
                       function(ind) {
                          gp_cur <- group[ind]
                          if(any(group[1:ind]!=gp_cur)) tail(value[1:ind][group[1:ind]!=gp_cur], 1) else NA
                       })]

df
 #            x group value own_lag other_lag
 #1: 2001-12-08     B     1      NA        NA
 #2: 2002-07-09     A     2      NA         1
 #3: 2002-10-10     B     7       1         2
 #4: 2007-01-04     A     5       2         7
 #5: 2008-03-27     A     9       5         7
 #6: 2008-08-06     B    10       7         9
 #7: 2010-07-15     A     4       9        10
 #8: 2012-06-27     A     8       4        10
 #9: 2014-02-21     B     6      10         8
#10: 2014-02-24     A     3       8         6
```

*Explanation of other_lag determination:* The idea is, for each observation, to look at the group value, if there is any group value different from current one, previous to current one, then take the last value, else, put NA.

**N.B.:** `other_lag` can be created without the need of data.table:

```
df$other_lag <- with(df, sapply(1:nrow(df), 
                                function(ind) {
                                 gp_cur <- group[ind]
                                 if(any(group[1:ind]!=gp_cur)) tail(value[1:ind][group[1:ind]!=gp_cur], 1) else NA
                               }))
```

Answer (score 6):

Another data.table approach similar to @Cath's:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(df)
DT[, vlag := shift(value), by=group]
DT[, volag := .SD[.(chartr("AB", "BA", group), x - 1), on=.(group, x), roll=TRUE, x.value]]
```

This assumes that A and B are the only groups. If there are more...

```
DT[, volag := DT[!.BY, on=.(group)][.(.SD$x - 1), on=.(x), roll=TRUE, x.value], by=group]
```

*How it works:*

`:=` creates a new column

`DT[, col := ..., by=]` does each assignment separately per `by=` group, essentially as a loop.

- The grouping values for the current iteration of the loop are in the named list `.BY`.
- The subset of data used by the current iteration of the loop is the data.table `.SD`.

`x[!i, on=]` is an anti-join, looking up rows of `i` in `x` and returning `x` with the matched rows dropped.

`x[i, on=, roll=TRUE, x.v]` ...

- looks up each row of `i` in `x` using the `on=` condition
- when no exact `on=` match is found, it "rolls" to the nearest previous value of the final `on=` column
- it returns `v` from the `x` table

For more details and intuition, review the startup messages shown when you type `library(data.table)`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure whether I got your question correctly, but if "own" and "other" refers to group A and B, then this might do the trick. I strongly assume there are more elegant ways to do this:

```
df.x <-  df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(value.lag=lag(value)) %>% 
  mutate(index=seq_along(group)) %>% 
  arrange(group)

df.a <- df.x %>%
  filter(group=="A") %>% 
  rename(value.lag.a=value.lag)

df.b <- df.x %>% 
  filter(group=="B") %>% 
  rename(value.lag.b = value.lag)

df.a.b <- left_join(df.a, df.b[,c("index", "value.lag.b")], by=c("index"))

df.b.a <- left_join(df.b, df.a[,c("index", "value.lag.a")], by=c("index"))

df.x <- bind_rows(df.a.b, df.b.a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (Pipe-Only approach)

```
  library(zoo)
  df %>%
     mutate(groupLag = lag(group),
         dupLag = group == groupLag) %>%
     group_by(dupLag) %>%
     mutate(valueLagHelp = lag(value)) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate(helper = ifelse(dupLag == T, NA, valueLagHelp)) %>%
     mutate(helper = case_when(is.na(helper) ~ na.locf(helper, na.rm=F),
                                   TRUE ~ helper)) %>%
     mutate(valAfterLag = lag(dupLag)) %>%
     mutate(otherLag = ifelse(is.na(lag(valueLagHelp)), lag(value), helper)) %>%
     mutate(otherLag = ifelse((valAfterLag | is.na(valAfterLag)) & !dupLag, 
     lag(value), otherLag)) %>% 
     select(c(x, group, value, ownLag, otherLag))
```

Sorry for the mess. 
What it does it that it first creates a group lag and creates a helper variable for the case when the group is equal to its lag (i. e. when two "A"s are subsequent. Then it groups by this helper variable and it assigns to all values which are dupLag == F the correct value. Now we need to take care of the ones with dupLag == T.

So, ungroup. We need a new lagged-value helper that assigns all dupLag == T an NA, because they are not correctly assigned yet.

What's next is that we assign all NAs in our helper the last non-NA value.
This is not all because we still need to take care of some dupLag == F data points (you get that when you look at the complete tibble). First, we basically just change the second data point with the first mutate(otherLag==... operation. The next operation finalizes everything and then we select the variables which we'd like to have in the end.